# Asterisk : play message to caller when entering a queue

Tags: asterisk, telephony

I am struggling with this : when entering a queue, I'd like to play a welcome message to the caller.

The caller enters first a short queue (`initQ`) without announce, then enters the `mynewQ` where I'd like to play a custom welcome message.

So far, I was able to play only the default `queue-youarenext.alaw` with :

Files `queues.conf` :

```
[general]

[initQ]
strategy=ringall                
timeout=15
member => PJSIP/111
member => PJSIP/112
member => PJSIP/112

[mynewQ]
strategy=ringall
timeout=120
context=mynewQ-context
ringinuse=no
member => PJSIP/111
member => PJSIP/112
member => PJSIP/113
announce-to-first-user = yes
periodic-announce = custom/bienvenue
```

And the dialplan:

```
...
exten = takeCall,1,Queue(initQ,Crn)
 same = n,Queue(mynewQ,Cn)

...
[mynewQ-context]

exten = 1,1,NoOp("mynewQ-context : key 1 pressed to leave a message")
 same = n,VoiceMail(999@boitevocale,start)
 same = n,Playback(goodbye)
 same = n,Hangup()
```

My goal here is to play my own welcome message `custom/bienvenue`

I've tried with `queue-thankyou`, `periodic-announce` an others found in the `queues.conf.sample` file, but no good result.

Since I have a context defined, I've also explored this, but I was not able to play a message when entering this context. The context is used to catch DTMF and then trigger actions : leave a message, ask to be called back, ... and that is working fine.

Comment: Where is your dialplan?

Comment: I've added more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way I've finally done it. Many thanks to `arheops` for his suggestion to alter hold music.

File `queues.conf` :

```
[general]

[initQ]
strategy=ringall                
timeout=15
member => PJSIP/111
member => PJSIP/112
member => PJSIP/112

[mynewQ]
strategy=ringall
timeout=120
context=mynewQ-context
musicclass=mynewQmoh
ringinuse=no
member => PJSIP/111
member => PJSIP/112
member => PJSIP/113
```

File `musiconhold.conf` :

```
[mynewQmoh]
mode=files
announcement=custom/bienvenue
directory=moh
```

And the dialplan remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
exten = enterQ,1,Answer
same => n,Playback(intro-message)
same => n,Queue(initQ,Crn)
```

Or add your message into musiconhold and ensure your hold music always start from start(see musiconhold.conf options).

Comment: Thanks, but not sure to got it : if playing the intro-message is done _before_ entering the Queue, the caller will have to wait until the end of the message (entering the queue) before being able to press a DTMF key. Callers who knows the message will want to press the key before the end of the announce !
I'd like to play the message when entering the queue.

Comment: Yes, he have to wait. Even more, when IVR message played in a queue he ALSO wait, queue DO NOT ring when IVR or time announce played. Also you can't press digits everywhere, only when announce played.

Comment: You can play in background using chan_spy or by altering hold music. You can accept 1 everyewhere by using features.conf feature. app_queue not support that at all.